# Unable to "point to" passed array of function pointers in C

Tags: c, arguments, function-pointers

I've been trying to pass an array of function pointers to a function.  Once in that function I need a pointer to that array of function pointers but I keep getting an error.  I'm able to do it when it isn't a function argument.

```
void (*(*PointerToFuncPtrArray)[2])(unsigned char data[], unsigned char length);
void (*FuncPtr[2])(unsigned char data[], unsigned char length) = {

    func1,
    func2,
}

void NotArguement(void)  // attempt to point to without passing as parameter
{
    PointerToFuncPtrArray = &FuncP;   // this works
}


//  attempt to pass as argument
void AsArguement((void (*ptr[])(unsigned char data[], unsigned char length))
{
   PointerToFuncPtrArray = &ptr;    // This throws error


}
```

This throws...

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl **[])(unsigned char [],unsigned char)' to 'void (__cdecl *(*)[2])(unsigned char [],unsigned char)'
```

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear!  `PointerToFuncPtrArray` has explicit size info; you're trying to assign an incomplete type (i.e. it's missing size info) to it.

Comment: In addition to the type conversion problem you have disbalanced `()` in `AsArguement` parameter declaration. There should be only one `(` after `AsArguement`. In reality, this is normally the error the compiler will report first. I wonder how you managed to overlook that. Is the the real code you were trying to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array declaration in function argument list decays to pointer declaration. So, your function parameter is not declared as an array (despite the misleading appearance). It is declared as a pointer-to-pointer, meaning that inside the function the array type is lost irreversibly.

The same error will be reported in this simple example

```
int x[2];
...
void foo(int a[2]) /* <- equivalent to `void foo(int *a)` */
{
  int (*p1)[2] = &x; /* <- OK */
  int (*p2)[2] = &a; /* <- ERROR: can't convert `int **` to `int (*)[2]` */
}
...
foo(x);
```

In the above example `a` is no longer an array. It is a pointer of `int *` type, meaning that `&a` has type `int **` and cannot be used to initialize an object of type `int (*)[2]`.

In C, the only way to pass an array to a function while preserving the "arrayness" of the argument is to pass it "by pointer to the whole array", as in

```
int x[2];
...
void foo(int (*a)[2])
{
  int (*p)[2] = a; /* <- OK */
}
...
foo(&x);
```

Note that the application of `&` operator "moved" from inside of the function to the point of the call.

The same modification in your code would look as follows

```
void AsArguement(void (*(*ptr)[2])(unsigned char data[], unsigned char length))
{
   PointerToFuncPtrArray = ptr;
}
```

You just have to remember to apply `&` operator to the array argument when you call this function.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for such a quick answer.

Comment: (*PointerToFuncPtrArray[0])(test, sizeof(test));
 (*PointerToFuncPtrArray[1])(test, sizeof(test));

The first line correctly calls the method func1, but the second gives an access violation.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry for the multiple comments.  Should be ...

(*PointerToFuncPtrArray)[1](test, 3);

Comment: @bassplayer142: So, how do you call it? In order to call through your `PointerToFuncPtrArray`, as declared in the original post, you have to do `(*PointerToFuncPtrArray)[0](...)`. Note how the `()` are placed. You have different placements of `()` in your comments. So which one are you using?

Comment: I might be a little confused on what you're asking..  The actual function call wasn't in the original post.  Afterwards I ran into the issue where...

(*PointerToFuncPtrArray[1])(test, 3);  // is the wrong way
(*PointerToFuncPtrArray)[1](test, 3);  // is the right way

Comment: @bassplayer142: I was referring to your comments right here. In the earlier comment you did `(*PointerToFuncPtrArray[1])(test, sizeof(test))`, which was incorrect. In the next comment you did `(*PointerToFuncPtrArray)[1](test, 3)`, which was correct.